# Sampling with "Math.random" sometimes selects duplicate items from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, discord.js

I am trying to give the items in the voice channel randomly to the items in the message content. but it chooses the same person again. how can I prevent this? also user like this for dont knowing discord.js ppl 
example = user = ["2222222", "21111112"]

```
let users = message.member.voiceChannel.members
.filter(y => y.user.id !== message.author.id)
.map(a => a.user.id);
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
var user = users[Math.floor(Math.random() * num)];
console.log(user);
let adi = message.guild.members.get(user);
liste += "" + adi.displayName + " adlı kullanıcının rolü " + rol + "\n";
oyuncular += " <@" + adi.user.id + "> ";

}
```

Comment: also num = parseInt in message content message like this; 1Banana 3Apple

Comment: how many users are in the array. where is `num` assigned? should you use a shuffle algorithm instead?

Comment: Math.random() gives a float between 0 and 1, maybe should you multiplicate it (by 1000 for eg), and modulo it via the users count...

Comment: so this command like this; !randomrole 1Banana 3Apple "num= parseInt in message content" and users array not always same its changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of random-selection methods, "roll" and "deal".  Roll can get the same value more than once, as in rolling dice.  Deal gets a different value, as in dealing cards.

You're using roll.  You need deal. You need to remove each value from further consideration as you choose it.

Let's say you've populated your `users` array, and now you want to deal `num` values from it.  To do this you removed each item from your array as you choose it. It's a job for [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  if (users.length <= 0) break
  const randex = Math.floor(Math.random() * users.length)
  const user = users.splice(randex, 1)[0]
  /* do what you want with this user */
}
```

Splice is a good choice for this; the [V8 Javascript engine](https://v8.dev/) developers worked hard to make it as efficient as possible.

You can test this by pasting the following code into your console REPL in your browser devtools.

```
(function deal (k, n) {
  function range1(i){return i?range1(i-1).concat(i):[]}
  const users = range1(n)
  for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    if (users.length <= 0) break
    const randex = Math.floor(Math.random() * users.length)
    const user = users.splice(randex, 1)[0]
    console.log (user)
  }
})(7, 52)
```

This is a simplification of the Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) shuffle algorithm mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976). That algorithm shuffles everything in the input array. But that's not necessary if you only need to sample a few items from a longer array.

Comment: See also explanations of a Fischer-Yates shuffle, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976.

Answer (score 0):

What is 'num' in your example?

Surely the following would work:

```
var user = users[Math.floor(Math.random() * users.length)];
```

Comment: still same.  let num = parseInt(x); x = message content

Comment: This is fine for a single choice.  It fails when you want to randomly shuffle the inputs.